Matrix and Lme4 - R [lme4]
I would like to run a mixed effect linear model using lme4. When I attempt to run it I get an error matrix is not avaliable. When I attempt to install Matrix I get a message matrix is not avaliable for my version of R.
I've tried:

installing with dependences
R.version.string
library(devtools)
library("devtools"); install_github("lme4/lme4",dependencies=TRUE, build_vignettes=FALSE)
oo <- options(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("lme4")
options(oo)
install.packages("lme4.0",repos=c("http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",getOption("repos")[["CRAN"]]))
every other solution I could find online

I know this is a common issue, just hoping for some insight on why the common solutions aren't working :/
